# swagger 2 documentation not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

i'm trying to implement api documentation using swagger2 and springfox.
my project isn't a spring boot or maven , it depend on xml files.

i have added the class :

> SwaggerConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;



@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ProductController.class)
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private static final String SWAGGER_API_VERSION = "1.0";
    private static final String LICENSE_TEXT = "License";
    private static final String title = "Products REST API";
    private static final String description = "RESTful API for Products";

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(title)
                .description(description)
                .license(LICENSE_TEXT)
                .version(SWAGGER_API_VERSION)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket productsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .pathMapping("/")
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex( "/*"))
                .build();
    }


}
```

so when i run the tomcat server it run normally without errors but when i put the following link :

> http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

nothing happens.
am i missing some configuration or any suggestion please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried to define UiConfiguration bean?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich thank you for your reply but i've managed to solve the problem and i will post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is solved after adding these statements in my

> spring-config.xml

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" mapping="swagger-ui.html"></mvc:resources>
        <mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" mapping="/webjars/**"></mvc:resources>
        <bean class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration" id="swagger2Config"/>
```